# c++ executable doesnt run in windows 7 - 64 bit incompatibility

Tags: c++, windows-7, 64-bit, compatibility

I wrote a simple c++ program to calculate quadratic equations. I compiled it on ubuntu linux with g++.

Here is the code by the way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a,b,c;
    double x,x2;
    cout<<"Give a: ";
    cin>>a;
    cout<<"Give b: ";
    cin>>b;
    cout <<"Give c: ";
    cin>>c;
    if (a==0)
    {
        if (b==0)
        {
            if (c==0)
            {
            cout<<"Solution indeterminable";
            return 0;
            }
            else 
            {
            cout<<"No solution";
            return 0;
            }   
        }
        else
        {
        x=-c/b;
        cout<<"The only root is x: "<<x;
        return 0;
        }

    }
    else
    {
    double b_sqr=b*b;
    if (b_sqr>4*b*c)
        {
        cout<<"Complex roots: ";
        return 0;
        }
    else if (b_sqr==4*b*c)
        {
        x=-b/(2*a);
        cout<<"The only solution is x: "<<x;
        return 0;
        }
    else
        {
            x=-b+(sqrt((b*b)-(4*a*c)))/(2*2);
            x2=-b-(sqrt((b*b)-(4*a*c)))/(2*2);
            cout<<"The first root is x1: "<<x;
            cout<<"The first root is x2: "<<x2;
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Now when i tried to run this on my x64 Windows 7, this is what i got:

**Unsupported 16 bit application:**

The program or feature equation.exe cannot start or run due to incompatibility with 64-bit versions of windows. Please contact the software vendor to ask if a 64-bit Windows compatible version is available

Well i am the author and i wrote simpe c++ to code it. Whats up with this compatibility thing?

How can i manage to run it in windows 7 x64?
Thanks!

Comment: You have to compile it for each environment it's being run on separately.

Comment: What chris said, and the "16-bit" thing is a red herring. Windows can't tell *what* it is, so it's calling it 16-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows cannot run executables that target other operating systems. You need to recompile with a compiler that targets Windows. For instance mingw is probably the most widely used GCC port for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with MinGW when I compiled files with extension .h; if I change the extension of the source file to .cpp before compilation, the executable is compatible with my 64-bit windows 7. The reason? No idea. I'm a newby.